# Copying subdata into empty texture in OpenGL ES / WebGL

Tags: opengl-es, textures, webgl

I have created a texture this way:

```
var tex = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
gl.texParameteri(...
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, w, h, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
```

Then I try to copy subdata from current framebuffer into it:

```
gl.copyTexSubImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, ox, oy, sx, sy, w, h);
```

It does not copy anything for the first time. Texture is still empty (contains zeros).

It works, when I call copyTexSubImage2D for the second time. It also works for the first time, if the size of subarea corresponds to the size of the texture.

I want to avoid sending real data at the beginning (takes too long) and copying larger areas than I need also takes too long.

Is it expected behavior, or it is a bug in Chromes WebGL? Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 2):

Let's test

```js
var gl = twgl.getWebGLContext(document.getElementById("c"));
var programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, ["vs", "fs"]);
var greenProgramInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, ["vs", "green-fs"]);

var arrays = {
  position: [-1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 0, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
};
var bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, arrays);
twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);

// make a texture for a framebuffer
var fbtex = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, fbtex);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 256, 256, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

// create a framebuffer and attach the texture
var fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, fbtex, 0);

// clear texture to green
//gl.clearColor(0, 1, 0, 1);
//gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
// Just to make sure let's render green instead of clear to green. (both work for me though)
gl.useProgram(greenProgramInfo.program);
twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, gl.TRIANGLES, bufferInfo);

// now make a texture
var tex = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 256, 256, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

// copy part of the fbtexture to it
// target, level, xoffset, yoffset, x, y, width, height
gl.copyTexSubImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60);

gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);

// now clear to red
gl.clearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

// Now render with the texture
gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
var uniforms = {
  u_texture: tex,
};
twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, uniforms);
twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, gl.TRIANGLES, bufferInfo);
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="//twgljs.org/dist/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<script id="vs" type="notjs">
attribute vec4 position;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;

void main() {
  gl_Position = position;
  v_texcoord = position.xy * 0.5 + 0.5;
}
</script>
<script id="fs" type="notjs">
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texcoord);
}
</script>
<script id="green-fs" type="notjs">
precision mediump float;

varying vec2 v_texcoord;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(0,1,0,1);
}
</script>
<div>If this works there should be a white (transparent) canvas with a green rectangle inside.</div>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Seems to work for me. Is it not working for you?

Comment: Ok, so the problem is more complex. I created 2 textures A, B, both initialized with "null". I set A as rendering target and render green color into it. Then I do   gl.copyTexSubImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, ... );  into B and it does not work.

Comment: Changed the sample. Still works for me. Is it not working for you?

Comment: Thank you. It is very strange. My problem happens in a complex task, when I have tens of textures and do hundreds of operations, so it is quite hard to track down the actual reason. I solved it by initializing buffer with zero array by now.

Comment: https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-render-to-texture.html : <<It's EXTREMELY IMPORTANT to remember to call gl.viewport and set it to the size of the thing your rendering to.>> but where is the viewport in your example?